# Why are my printed outputs different?

Tags: swift, loops

I've been slowly building up skillsets in Swift. Drawing with loops is a great way I find, to understand the subtleties of the language.

Here is an interesting puzzle I can't quite figure out:
I've been trying to generate a truncated pyramid like this for a little while.

I finally got a rough one produced using a for loop. [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4U6z.png)  BUT, as you can see, one of my earlier attempts generated a half truncated pyramid.

The only difference between the two is that on lines 19 and 33, the variable "negativeSpaceThree" is diminished by 2 and 1 respectively.

Can anyone explain why the outputs are so different? I'd really like to understand these nuances. It might simply be my math, but I'm wondering if its a bug.

Many thanks for any input offered.

Code added below:

```
let space = " "


var negativeSpaceTwo = 22
var xTwo = 3

for  circumTwo in 1...11{
    xTwo += 2
    negativeSpaceTwo -= 2

    print(String(repeating: "-", count: negativeSpaceTwo) , String(repeating:"*", count: xTwo ))
}


print(space)
print(space)

var negativeSpaceThree = 11
var xThree = 3

for  circumTwo in 1...11{
    xThree += 2
    negativeSpaceThree -= 1

    print(String(repeating: "-", count: negativeSpaceThree) , String(repeating:"*", count: xThree ))
}
```

Comment: Post *code,* not a screenshot (funny that the screenshot has no lines 19 and 33 which you refer to).

Comment: Debug your code by setting breakpoints on your `print` statements so you can examine the variables for each loop iteration.

Comment: And of course the output is different because the loops are different. Take a piece of paper and make a table with the values of the two relevant variables: You should see it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for such quick replies everyone!  I apologize re posting a screenshot rather than the code itself.  I'll remember to do that the next time for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the difference in how many `*` characters you are printing on each line. If your total line length is `total = dashes + stars` and you subtract 2 from `dashes` each time while adding 2 to `stars` each time, the total line length will remain the same.

In the second pyramid, you reduce the `dashes` by one, but add 2 to `stars`, so the total length increases by 1 each line, giving the pyramid effect on the right-hand side of the text.

Comment: I get it now!  Thanks so much for that insight. It blows my mind how one person can immediately see where the issue is, whereas someone staring at it for hours is missing the same thing.

Comment: haha sometimes we just get caught up in the details and it's hard to look at things simply